# padding and line-height issue on mac and safari

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, cross-browser

I am currently  working on http://stansgarage.mercury.grayhatweb.com/ site. 
And it is working well in windows in any browser.

But there is some issue on mac and safari for heading(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6). 
Line-height or padding of mac  is not same as windows. I don't use mac and
it is very difficult to check for me.

My css code is :

```
  .main-content-left-title h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 26px; 
    }
```

Comment: What is your Question here ?

Comment: Do you use reset css or not??

Comment: Title is not showing in correct in correct form on mac as in windows.

I am using foundation css framework for this site.

Comment: try setting the ratio instead of pixels, eg line-height: 1.4444;  instead of 24px. (eg 24px/18px) this solved my line-height issues on ios safari...